# Jquery not scrolling to div id

Tags: jquery

I am currently attempting to scroll to a certain div id using jquery.

The code is below.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var prevScrollTop = 0;
    var $scrollDiv    = jQuery('div#container');
    var $currentDiv   = $scrollDiv.children('div:first-child');

    var $sectionid    = 1;
    var $numsections  = 5;

    $scrollDiv.scroll(function(eventObj)
    {
        var curScrollTop = $scrollDiv.scrollTop();
        if (prevScrollTop < curScrollTop)
        {
        // Scrolling down:
            if ($sectionid+1 > $numsections) {
                console.log("End Panel Reached");
            }
            else {
                $currentDiv = $currentDiv.next().scrollTo();
                console.log("down");
                console.log($currentDiv);
                $sectionid=$sectionid+1;
                console.log($currentDiv.attr('id'));
                var divid =$currentDiv.attr('id');
                jQuery('html, body').animate({scrollTop:jQuery('#'+divid).position().top}, 'slow');
                }
        }
        else if (prevScrollTop > curScrollTop)
        {
        // Scrolling up:
            if ($sectionid-1 == 0) {
                console.log("Top Panel Reached");
            }
            else {
                $currentDiv = $currentDiv.prev().scrollTo();
                console.log("up");
                console.log($currentDiv);
                $sectionid=$sectionid-1;
                var divid =$currentDiv.attr('id');
                jQuery('html, body').animate({scrollTop:jQuery('#'+divid).position().top}, 'slow');

                }
        }
        prevScrollTop = curScrollTop;
    });
});
```

I can verify from the chrome console that all the values (i.e. the div id) are correct.
Yet, there is no animation at all.

The website goes like this.

```
<div id="header">
<!-- Floating Header -->
</div>
<div id="container">
    <div id="panel1">
        <!--content of panel1 -->
    </div>
    <div id="panel2">
       <!--content of panel2 -->
    </div>
    <div id="panel3">
        <!--content of panel3 -->
    </div>
</div>
```

The part that needs scrolling are the 100% width/height panels, which are inside the container, which is a scrolling div.

Comment: can you share the same in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: Do you have the .scrollTo plugin included?

Comment: @MLM: [`scrollTop()`](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) is a jQuery method, not a plug-in. Unless I'm misunderstanding something? (This is, of course, *entirely possible!*)

Comment: @DavidThomas He has written $currentDiv = $currentDiv.next()**.scrollTo();** in his code.

Comment: @MLM: ah, I missed that. I suspect typo, rather than plug-in though. =)

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it.

FYI, since the divs are in the container div...

```
jQuery('html, body').animate({scrollTop:jQuery('#'+divid).position().top}, 'slow');
```

should be

```
jQuery('#container').animate({scrollTop:jQuery('#'+divid).position().top}, 'slow');
```